# How to generate PDF using custom link in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, pdf-generation, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have a Visualforce page PDF_Generate which generates a PDF.

I created a custom link in Account object with URL

`{!URLFOR('/apex/PDF_Generate')}?source=HC_DOC_Acc&id={!Account.Id}`

The URL generated from visualforce page is

`https://mycompany--cch.visualforce.com/apex/PDF_Generate?source=HC_DOC_Acc&id=0014m000003P6HY`

But what the custom link generates URL

`https://mycompany--d.visualforce.com/apex/PDF_Generate?source=HC_DOC_Acc&id=0014m000003P6HY`

How to change the --d.visualforce.com in the URL to --cch.visualforce.com.

Comment: Do both links _work_? Why do you want or need to change one?

Comment: Now it works fine. I created a custom setting for the URL

Comment: isn't the part after `--` name of the sandbox? It should generate properly wherever you deploy it without any special action from you... And you could use URLFOR bit smarter, it has "room" for passing parameters too which will save you some headache with encoding special characters etc...